# Firebase and React with react-snapshot (pre-rendering)

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, prerender

I"m new to firebase, just wrote a little simple test react component before putting all of data on to firebase, but unfortunately I couldn't make it work with Server Side Pre-Rendering. It's very important to make it SEO friendly for me, and I've searching around on the internet for the solution, but still couldn't really figure it out. please help me out with this. thanks very much in advance.

The simple code below will only generate the initial state with React-Snapshot, when I open the the page it will show initial state and then update to newer state. But I need to make the initial state object fetching data directly from Firebase and generate static html with React-Snapshot.

```
class FirebaseTestingComponent extends Component {
constructor(){
  super();
  this.state = { 
    speed: 10
  };

}

componentWillMount(){
  const rootRef = firebase.database().ref().child('react');
  const speedRef = rootRef.child('speed');
  speedRef.on('value', snap => {
    this.setState({
      speed: snap.val()
    });
  });
}


render(){
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{this.state.speed}</h1>
    </div>

  ); 

}
```

}

Comment: Chun, are u still using react-snapshot or server-side render?

Comment: also does firebase hosting automagically fallback to 200.html if a route is not covered by react-snapshot?

Comment: @jasan it doesn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By SEO friendly I assume you want static content instead of dynamic (not an expert on SEO) but firebase runs asynchronously especially when you use .on() that's like websocket, doesn't matter if you do willmount or didmount this case.
My humble suggestion for the design is to fetch from firebase in your server before render the page (firebase support java and node for sure, not sure about the rest), and set initial state with that value you fetched, that will guarantee your initial state is from firebase. From that you can still use that .on() for later value coming in.

Comment: thanks very much for your advice. It really makes a lot of sense as you described. Really appreciate it.

Comment: no problem, mark me as correct answer if you agree with my opinion. thanks